# Translucent node produces weird result

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm following this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/y7PdiGXbrD0?t=49

At the above time mark, my out is:

[image]

The branches are cropped images as plane. My guess is that, the cuts should have been made closer to the leaves but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hello :). CG Geek switched to Cycles engine mid-way. And you're using Eevee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @Jachym Michal (comments). Cycles does not produce the plane around the branches.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100016)

Comment: It did solve my problem so it is in fact a valid answer to the question. "To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post." It solved my problem, really :) . I don't need to "critique or request clarification from an author". Eeve was indeed the problem :P